# JTable getting values of specific column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How could I get the values under specific column in JTable

example :

```
_________________________
| Column 1  | Column 2  |
________________________
|     1     | a         |
________________________
|     2     | b         |
________________________
|     3     | c         |
_________________________
```

How could I get the values under Column 1  that is [1, 2, 3]
In the form of  some data structure ( preferable array)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0;i<table.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
{
    list.add(table.getModel().getValueAt(i,0)); //get the all row values at column index 0
}
```